# Will the Excel "Date()" function will corrected, in order to handle older years (before 1900)?

Tags: excel, date

I was just having a look at [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75245858) and I thought "But why don't you use the standard Excel's `Date()` function", but after some tryouts, I understood why:

```
Year Month Day   ±Date(Y, M, D)
2023    04  08   08/04/2023
1734    04  08   08/04/3634 => wrong! (3634 = 1734 + 1900)
1899    04  08   08/04/3799 => wrong! (3799 = 1899 + 1900)
1900    04  08   08/04/1900
```

[The Microsoft webpage about the `Date()` function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349) does not mention anything about this bug. Is there any knowledge on when this will be tackled?

Comment: Same for me - I wanted to post that solution as well. I found this one: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-systems-in-excel-e7fe7167-48a9-4b96-bb53-5612a800b487 - where you can see that only dates from 1.1.1900 are supported.

Comment: @Ike: indeed dates from before 1900 are not mentioned, but I would expect Excel to give an error in that case instead of a "bogus" value, so I'm wondering if Microsoft is planning solving that issue.

Comment: That behavior is well documented by Microsoft in their description of the function:  [Date Function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349#:~:text=The%20DATE%20function%20returns%20the%20sequential%20serial%20number,the%20first%20date%20is%20January%201%2C%201900.%20). I suppose you could send them a suggestion, but I doubt there will be any change since the behavior is documented and others may rely on it.

Comment: Yes as @RonRosenfeld stated everything is documented and not a bug, but expected outcome: "If year is between 0 (zero) and 1899 (inclusive), Excel adds that value to 1900 to calculate the year. For example, DATE(108,1,2) returns January 2, 2008 (1900+108)." Quesion "Will they do that or that" is speculative and a little bit off-topic.

Comment: @user11222393: you're right, I hadn't seen that on the webpage. I'll close my question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the mentioned "bad behaviour" is described on the mentioned webpage, which makes it not erroneous.